# Unable to download file into AppData folder

Tags: c#

im trying to write some code which downloads a file and saves it in AppData, but for some reason I keep getting an exception during the `DownloadFile()` call.

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: An exception occurred during a WebClient
>   request.

Here is my code:

```
string remoteUri = "http://mhost.site11.com/";
            string fileName = "SysSpec.zip", myStringWebResource = null;

            string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

            // Create a new WebClient instance.
            using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
                    // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
                    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, appData + "\\PPA\\" + fileName);
                }
                catch (WebException er)
                {
                    var result = GetResponceFromWebException(er);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
                    }

                    throw;
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());     
                }
            }
        }
        private HttpRequestResponce GetResponceFromWebException(WebException e)
        {
            HttpRequestResponce result = null;
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = e.Response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (stream != null)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                var responce = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response);

                                result = new HttpRequestResponce(responseString, responce.StatusCode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // log exception or do nothing or throw it
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

---

Solution:

Download the file to the directory my Program is in first then move it.

```
string remoteUri = "http://mhost.site11.com/";
            string fileName = "SysSpec.zip", myStringWebResource = null;

            string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

            // Create a new WebClient instance.
            using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
                // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);

                // Move the file
                string path = fileName;
                string path2 = appData + "\\PPA\\" + fileName;

                try
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        // This statement ensures that the file is created, 
                        // but the handle is not kept. 
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) { }
                    }

                    // Ensure that the target does not exist. 
                    if (File.Exists(path2))
                        File.Delete(path2);

                    // Move the file.
                    File.Move(path, path2);
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", er.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Check the WebException.Status

Comment: You could see the example of getting the data from web exception response object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675121/how-to-catch-exception/30675651#30675651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might run into permission issues writing to that folder. Check whether your process has write permissions for AppData folder. If you are using IIS, the user you must allow is in the form `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` where you must replace DefaultAppPool with your app pool name.

Comment: I'm not using IIS or any server on my machine, must I have a server running on the machine locally?

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? Isn't it a web application?

Comment: No it's a Windows WPF Application in C#

Comment: Ok, the AppData folder got me confused. Check if your user has write permission to that folder. If it's located in a "sensible" zone of your file system, you might also have to run your application elevated.

Comment: Also, make sure the PPA subfolder exists before making the call to DownloadFile. I'm not sure it will create it for you.